# DocumentBeforeSave & UserForm autoopen don't work together

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

Using App_DocumentBeforeSave (in Class1), and Document_New with Call Register_Event_Handler in ThisDocument, I cannot use my usual code to open up a Userform (Autoopen, AutoNew).

How should I place code to allow both DocumentBeforeSave code as well as Userform initiation code?

Sorry for not being more clear.  In the template with the working code for changes to a document BeforeSave:
In Microsoft Word Project ThisDocument:

```
Private Sub Document_Open() 
Call Register_Event_Handler
End Sub

Private Sub Document_New()
Call Register_Event_Handler
End Sub
```

In Modules, Module1:

```
Dim X As New Class1
Public Sub Register_Event_Handler()
    Set X.App = Word.Application
End Sub
```

In Class Modules, Class1:

```
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
‘
‘  Then follows my clean up code in this Sub, which also Calls Subs, which are also placed in Class1 under this Sub.
```

All this works as intended.  However, I wrote the code above for all of the Templates we use to generate medical reports, many of which also bring up UserForms upon opening.  However, all my templates with UserForms have this code in In Microsoft Word Project ThisDocument to open the Userform whenever the document or template opens:

```
 Sub Autoopen()
        Options.ButtonFieldClicks = 1
    MACROS.Show
    With MACROS
        .Top = Application.Top
        .LEFT = Application.LEFT
    End With    
End Sub

Private Sub Document_New()    
    Options.ButtonFieldClicks = 1
    MACROS.Show
    With MACROS
        .Top = Application.Top
        .LEFT = Application.LEFT
End With    
End Sub
```

I cannot get the Userform opening code to work with the initializing code for the DocumentBeforeSave – for one thing they both use Sub Document_New().  I tried changing the Userform opening code to Sub AutoNew(), which still didn’t function.

The Userforms without the DocumentBeforeSave code open fine, and the DocumentBeforeSave code works OK without the Userform code.  How do I get both to work in the same project? BTW - the error that occurs: it won't save the project/document.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're actually doing here: adding your code (or at least the relevant parts of it) typically helps clarify things.

Answer (score 1):

AutoOpen, AutoNew and AutoSave belong in a "plain vanilla" module. It looks like you've tried putting them in a class, which won't work...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: HI Glen. Thank you for your thoughts. Yes this IS the answer to the question. I had to read the question a number of times before I could isolate the real question: the Auto macros are not firing. The OP wants the Auto macros to fire. They will not fire if they're in a Class module; the must be in a "plain" module, then they should fire.

Comment: Ok, just be aware that including a question in an answer almost immediately causes reviewers and moderators to classify an answer as commentary on a question. Next time I'd ask a question as a comment and if the clarification helps, provide an answer in lieu of their feedback.

Comment: Cindy - not sure I understand your suggestion: my Auto subs are all in ThisDocument (both for the BeforeSave code and the initial opening of the UserForms.  Are you saying they should not be in ThisDocument?  What is a "plain vanilla" module?  In a nutshell, how have others employed auto opening of Userforms & BeforeSave code in the same project?  Thnx

Comment: ThisDocument is, itself, a class module that represents the Document object. In the VBA Editor: Insert/Module creates a "plain vanilla" module. Copy the Auto macros to that (and commment them out or delete them in the class module).